# changing textureRect of a CCSprite created by CCRenderTexture

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCSprite` which gradually needs to be exhausted linearly from one end, lets say from left to right.For this purpose ,I am trying to change the `textureRect` property of the sprite so that the part that got exhausted from one end is 'outside' the displaying frame of the sprite.

I did this sort of thing before with a sprite that gets loaded from a spritesheet.And it worked perfectly.But I created this `CCSprite` using `CCRenderTexture` and by changing the `textureRect` property,the entire sprite gets disappeared.

The first image is the original CCSprite which I get from CCRenderTexture.The second image shows what I want to achieve.The black dotted rectangular portion of the Sprite needs to be omitted out.Only the blue dotted portion of the sprite needs to be displayed.Essentially,this blue dotted rectangle is my textureRect.

[image: changing textureRect property to show only portion of the whole sprite]

Is there any way how I could make my sprite reduce from one end.
Also is there any difference between a sprite created normally,and one created using `CCRenderTexture`.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? Words only are not clear enough.

Comment: just made an edit.Have a look

Comment: I have done similar thing like this before using some low-level hack. I can't provide the code directly since is business secret and core part of one of my projects. But I can share you some solutions.

There is a work around solution if you use `CCProgressTimer`, that's very easy and I think it should be enough for you.

If you have some `special` requirements like "how can I remove a circle part of the sprite", then some low-level hack is needed. I think you should show the code how you create CCSprite with CCRenderTexture to us.

Comment: What if I want to exhaust it from both the ends at once?Front and back,while my sprite position remains in between?As i said before,I did this sort of trick with a batched CCSprite.All I need to do there was to set its textureRect property.But this CCSprite is through a CCRenderTexture.I don't know how to put the code in comments but its pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar thing like this before using some low-level hack.

There is a work around solution if you use `CCProgressTimer`, that's very easy and I think it should be enough for your examples.

But you said in comment that you have some `special` requirements like "exhaust it from both the ends at once" then some low-level hack is needed. My solution from my last object is:

1) Get the texture image's raw data. In cocos2d you can use `CCRenderTexture` and in cocos2d-x you can use `CCImage`.

2) `CCRenderTexture` has a method of `- (BOOL) saveToFile:      (NSString *)    name
format:     (tCCImageFormat)    format`
. You can read its source code then try to save it into an 2D array instead like `byte raw[1024][768]`. Each element in this array represents one pixel on your picture(the type may not be `byte`, I'm not sure, nearly forget the details). The format MUST BE PNG since transparency will be needed.

3) Modify raw data directly, set pixel's transparency to 0x0 which you want it to disappear.

4) Re-initialize a `CCRenderTexture` using picture data you modified.

I can't provide the code directly since is a trade secret and core part of one of my projects. But I can share you my solution. You also need some knowledge about how PNG file works. Read:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was making a silly mistake.While supplying values to the textureRect(CGRect),I was actually setting the textureRect.origin.y to the height of the texture which made my textureRect go beyond(above) the texture area.This explains why they were disappearing.